# CSS file only updating on renaming on Apache server

Tags: css, apache, caching, server, web-development-server

I have been trying to do some changes to my CSS, but it seems like the CSS files don't update. Already tried clearing browser cache and disabling server cache with `.htaccess`

However, they only update when I change my file name to something new with additional changes. Like renaming `app.css` to `app1.css` updates the file, but to make more changes I have to rename again to something like `app.css` or `app2.css` with more additional changes. I have tried to create a new CSS file and to embed it, but that didn't work as well.

Anyone faced something similar or know what might be causing it? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you have probably another layer of caching, this is a common situation of cache issue. By the way no need to rename, append a version `app.css?v=2`

Comment: Just a work around, you could call the CSS file with a version number on the end app.css?v=1.01 and you would only have to change the version number in your header. As for solving it, it could depend on your hosting provider.

Comment: I added `<?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); ?>` after my CSS link in the header for development use. Would work for now. Will probably remove it after making all the changes. Thanks for the idea